# zero value of a pointer with %v and %p in Golang

Tags: go, pointers

I am confusing the outputs provided by %p and %v format verbs of a pointer

```
var a *int
// zero value of a is:
fmt.Printf("%v", a) // <nil>
// using %p 
fmt.Printf("%p", a) // 0x0
```

We know that %v uses %p as the default formatter, then why %v showing `<nil>` as output?

The zero value of an uninitialized pointer is `<nil>`, then why %p outputting `0x0` instead ?

As per Go docs, %p uses base 16 notation with leading 0x, if so, is `<nil>` and `0x0` are same?

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/fmt

Comment: `%v` doesn't promise to be exactly the same as `%p` when the value is a pointer, and as you can see, it is not. Your question has 3 questions in it. Can you clarify a single question you're asking?

Comment: The default format for %v is:

bool:                    %t
int, int8 etc.:          %d
uint, uint8 etc.:        %d, %#x if printed with %#v
float32, complex64, etc: %g
string:                  %s
chan:                    %p
pointer:                 %p

Comment: `<nil>` and `0x0` are of course the same for a pointer, it's just a matter of formatting for human readability based on context. There's no perfect solution, and `%v` chooses you show any nil value as `<nil>`. Since they both mean the same thing, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: finally, I knew the value of nil in base 16 is 0x0. Maybe my question is confusing to you, I want to know whether nil and 0x0 are the same. Yes, you clarified. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

1. `v` is the generic value verb and it prints nil pointers as `<nil>` because that makes most sense as a generic formatting. Note the word "default" in its description: It uses `p` as *default*, not unconditionally.
2. `p` prints pointer values and thus prints a nil pointer as `0x0`. Note that `p` and `v` are different verbs.
3. Yes, nil pointers are 0. But note that the strings `<nil>` and `0x0` are not "the same".

(Tip: It is *incredibly* hard to learn things by trying to be clever with `fmt.Printf` as it contains a lot of (sensible) magic.)